# $\pi$ is a fiber bundle over $B$... Difficulty interpreting some Wikipedia definitions

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

Let (i)$\left(F \xrightarrow{\quad \quad} E \xrightarrow{\quad \pi \quad}B \right)$ be any fiber bundle.

Wikipedia has a different parlance when defining some fiber bundles. Take this excerpt from the article on bundle maps:

---

Let (ii)$\left( E \xrightarrow{\quad \pi_E \quad }  \mathfrak M \xleftarrow{\quad \pi_F \quad } F\right)$ be fiber bundles over a space $ \mathfrak M$. Then a bundle map from $E$ to $F$ over $\mathfrak M$ is a continuous map $\left( E \xrightarrow{\quad \varphi \quad} F \right)$ such that $\bigg(  \pi_F \circ \varphi = \pi_E \bigg)$.

---

(a)

In lieu of (i): "$\left( E \xrightarrow{\quad \pi_E \quad} \mathfrak M\right)$ is a fiber bundle over a space $\mathfrak M$" is **only** a terse way to state that we have a bundle $\left(F \xrightarrow{\quad \quad} E \xrightarrow{\quad \pi \quad} \mathfrak M \right)$? If so, then what is the $F$ that Wikipedia is using? Like $E$ another total space?

(b)

Assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that $E$ and  $F$ in (ii) the same $E$ and $F$ in (i), then is $\varphi$ a map from the fiber to the total space?

---

I saw no clarification for any of these questions on the main Wikipedia page for fiber bundles. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If by (i) you mean that $\pi$ is a fiber bundle over $B$ with total space $E$ and fiber $F$, then (ii) doesn't mean the same thing as (i).

Comment: You actually don't need the $F \to E$ part to define a fiber bundle. It's only written to remind you what the fiber looks like, and to resemble an exact sequence.

Comment: Thanks guys, I cleaned things up for you and rewrote (a) to be more precise. For your convenience, (ii) is only stating then that we have a bundle $\left(F \xrightarrow{\quad \quad} E \xrightarrow{\quad \pi \quad} \mathfrak M \right)$? @Trebor, if Wikipedia just omits the $\left( F \xrightarrow{\quad \quad} \right)$ part in (ii), then what is $F$ as used in the Wikipedia definition? Another total space?

Comment: Maybe it's high time to start reading textbooks, rather than relying on Wikipedia. You need to understand that $F$ represents the fiber of $E$ over each point of $B$ in (i), whereas it represents a *different* fiber bundle in (ii). They are not indicating the fibers. Maybe you should go back and read an old classic, *Fiber Bundles* by Husemoller.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the clarification on (ii). I'll look at the textbook rec.